# Laravel/Eloquent: querying a belongsTo / hasMany relation

Tags: sql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have 2 tables : **tasks** and **executions**. A *task* "hasMany" *executions* (and an *execution* "belongsTo" a *task*).

Fields in table *tasks*: `id (primary key), name, data, created_at, ...`
Fields in table *executions*: `id (primary key), process_name, created_at, task_id.`

I want to get the **oldest task** (based on *tasks.created_at*) which,
- has never been been executed (no record in table *executions* with the task id as task_id),
    **OR**
- has been executed by any other process but "MyProcess" => executions.process_name <> 'MyProcess'

I read the Eloquent doc and find the "Querying Relationship Existence" but I can't find how to query non-existence.

How can I do (I hope I was clear enough)?
Thank you very much in advance, I'm stuck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should set up your relationships:

```
class Task extends Model {
    public function executions() {
        return $this->hasMany(Execution::class);
    }
}

class Execution extends Model {
    public function task() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
    }
}
```

Then your query should be:

```
$task = Task::doesntHave('executions')
            ->orWhereHas('executions', function($query) use ($name) {
                return $query->where('process_name', '<>', $name);
            })
            ->oldest()
            ->first();
```

Of course you could wrap those queries in a query scope.

Comment: Thank very much! That's exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT t.* FROM tasks t 
LEFT JOIN executions e 
ON e.task_id = t.id AND e.process_name = 'MyProcess'
WHERE e.task_id IS NULL
ORDER BY t.create_at LIMIT 1
```